# Growl does not pass on Tweets to Notification Center

Tags: notifications, twitter, growl

I've recently switched to Mountain Lion, which means that I now have Notification Center.

I'm using the [Twitter app](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12) by Twitter, and on my previous system I used Growl to display tweets. Now, however, nothing is showing up. Notification center does not seem to care much for regular tweets (without mentions), and suddenly Growl doesn't show them either.

A difference with my previous setup is that I downloaded the newest version of Growl now - it has evolved out of a prefpane and is now an app. I did confirm that it worked, though, as a Colloquy (IRC) mention did show up.

In the preferences of Twitter I did set 'Tweets' to show via Growl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating this question, I figured it out.

Twitter was not yet listed in the Growl preferences as an app that was outputting to Growl. Simply restarting the Twitter app fixed this. Oddly enough this wasn't necessary for Adium or Colloquy.

[image]

Works fine now! Channeling the notifications to Notification Center strips them of profile images and the Twitter program icon, so I'm sticking to Growl's defaults.